# Different before and after animations on CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I want to do the following with a navbar:

On hover, the item disappears, and is replaced by the same text with a different colour.

the after animation I want something different (such as a 360 degree rotation) and then original span appends.

I can get the first animation to work, but can't modify what happens after without changing the first.

Working JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/whgeL8kw/

the css:

```
.nav-item {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 0;
  margin-left:-12px;
  margin-right:-12px;
}

.nav-item span {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.nav-item > a > span {
  font-family: Montserrat, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-item > a:before,
.nav-item > a:after {
  font-family: Montserrat, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: lightblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}


.nav-item > a:before {
  font-family: Montserrat, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  content: attr(data-hover);
/*  -webkit-transform: translate(0,150%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,150%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,150%);
  -o-transform: translate(0,150%);*/
  transform: translateY(150%);
}


.nav-item > a:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,150%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,150%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,150%);
  -o-transform: translate(0,150%);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.nav-item > a:hover span,
.nav-item > a:active span {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-item > a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
  -o-transition-delay: .4s;
  transition-delay: .4s;
}
.nav-item > a:active:after {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
  -o-transition-delay: .4s;
  transition-delay: .4s;
}

.nav-item > a:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correct, You would like to do a set of animations.

If that's the case, You can accomplish the task by using [CSS animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: Yes, although it's not as simple as chaining animations -- I want to delay the second thing until after they stop hovering... 

But I'll play around a bit with this.